# How can I express "you make a.../you'd make for a..."?

Tags: expressions

Do you know the English expression, "you make a"?

It's pretty simple:

> You make a fine wife.

It might be more correct as

> You'd make for a...

but they're tenses are different then. I could be using it incorrectly, but that's okay.

I saw my friend in a red cloak-like jacket and wanted to say, "you make a cute Red Riding Hood" or "you'd make a cute Red Riding Hood", but got hung up after かわいい赤ずきんに. I was thinking なられる。 But it didn't feel like what I wanted to say.

Is there a similar expression to what I was thinking?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You make a fine wife. 
「君はいい奥さんになるよ」/「君はいい奥さんになれるよ」
You'd make a cute Red Riding Hood.
「かわいい赤ずきんになれるよ」

Comment: Hmm..okay, maybe I should be more confident =)