# How does adding なる make this phrase more "natural"?

Tags: word-choice, usage, phrases

Recently, I wanted to express the sentence "*Maybe they'd make good pets.*" in Japanese. I initially tried to say it as such:

> [多分]{たぶん}いいペットでしょうね！

I was then corrected by a native speaker, and he told me that it would sound more *natural* if I expressed it this way:

> [多分]{たぶん}いいペット**になる**でしょうね！

Now, what exactly does this add to the sentence? I believe that in this case, なる is being used to mean "*to become*" (It's hard to tell for sure since I don't have a kanji for reference.) Was it added simply to make the expression more idiomatic, or is there a more grammatical reason behind it?

Answer (score 7):

Simply translate them carefully.

> 多分、いいペットでしょうね.
>   'Probably, they are good pets'.
>
> 多分、いいペットになるでしょうね.
>   'Probably, they will become good pets'.

Don't you think the second one is closer to the meaning you wanted?

If you want to emphasize it is an assumption, you can say

> いいペットになりそうですね.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I don't know if it makes sense given the context of the converstation. I had no intention of actually making the subject (we were talking about _lions_) my pet. It was meant as a funny exaggeration and the native speaker knew it. In a case like this, なる seems a bit _strong_, if you know what I mean. Could it possibly have carried a slightly different nuance?

Comment: Why is なる too strong?

Comment: The thing is, with your first sentence, you assume they are already pets. And your 多分 is about that they might be good at "being pets".

Comment: @sawa なる makes me feel like I truly had an intention of making one a pet. It seems very direct to me. But I see that you've added another possibility by using そう, which sounds better to me. Could this still carry the nuance of an exaggeration given the context?

Comment: @Miguel in my question on how to say "[make for a...](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4262/how-can-i-express-you-make-a-youd-make-for-a)" なる felt like the logical choice, as leaving it out would sound pretty much like the statement in sawa's first translation. I was looking for the word that would add that supposedness, and it seems it is なる.

Comment: @Miguel What is the basis of your feeling that なる implies intention?

Comment: @sawa I feel it might imply intention indirectly, because if they are to "_become pets_", they can't (normally) do it on their own, but rather someone else must make them their pet. Of course, this probably stems from a more westernized mode of thinking, though.

Comment: @Miguel If the English word "become" has that nuance (which I am not sure), then the problem is not with Japanese, nor with English. The problem is with the transation for the word. It is not a good translation for なる. Perhaps, "turn into" is better.

Comment: The core issue here seems to me to be that only sentences that can take a "future" interpretation can be hypothetical ("will"->"would"). でしょう can only be interpreted in the present (why? why is "will be" impossible?) and so "would be" doesn't work. Perhaps?

Comment: @Hyperworm A hypothesis does not have to be about future. You might not know whether some animal is a pet of someone at the moment, or whether it was one.

Comment: @sawa That's true, isn't it... Hm, I thought I was on to something. :(

Comment: AFAIK, I think @Hyperworm is right in the sense that でしょう can only be be interpreted in the present, and in this case, it is probably what makes it hard to translate this type of expression directly.

Comment: It isn't true of でしょう in general, though -- `明日は雨でしょう` is valid, right? I don't know why でしょう has to be present here... (sorry if I've added a bunch of confusion to this comment thread)

Comment: @Miguel Sawa's sentence "probably, they will become good pets" feels too strong to you? is that because it says "will" instead of "would"? but how do you say "would" in japanese? can you even??

Comment: @ogicu8abruok Japanese does have subjunctives, but I don't know if it will fit here.

Comment: @Miguel As Hyperworm is correcting your interpretion, でしょう can cooccur with non-past or past. There is no such thing as present tense in Japanese, though.